# How to customize SharePoint 2016 server role?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, 2016, server

I have 1 App Server and 1 Web Server,

I want combine the Search Role and  Application Role to 1 App Server.

How do I do this? I'm trying to change to use custom role, but i dont know how to add the Search service to App Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the app related functions on 1 server then your should convert or configure your App server with custom.this is what we had in 2013 everything in one.

Now you can configure all the services you want.

Answer (score 1):

After you switched to Custom role, you must modify the existing search-topology to move the components to another server. You have to do this via PowerShell, there's no GUI for it.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj862354.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Custom role instead of the Search and Application role.